# Facebook Ads Api Getting Leadgen Form Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

How can i get LeadgenForm values with in time range.

```
LeadgenForm form = new LeadgenForm(FormID);

Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

parameters.Add("date_preset", "today");

object x = form.GetLeads(null, parameters);
```

I 'am using Facebook Ads API SDK for C-sharp but
i cannot find correct parameter name for getting today's form values.